# How to install Plesk on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: installation, ubuntu-16.04, plesk, failed-installation, plesk-onyx

I am getting this error on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
plesk-php56-snmp : Depends: libsnmp30 (>= 5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4.1~dfsg) but 5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4 is to be installed
plesk-php70-snmp : Depends: libsnmp30 (>= 5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4.1~dfsg) but 5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4 is to be installed
plesk-php71-snmp : Depends: libsnmp30 (>= 5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4.1~dfsg) but 5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4 is to be installed
plesk-php72-snmp : Depends: libsnmp30 (>= 5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4.1~dfsg) but 5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4 is to be installed
```

---

output of  **lsb_release -a** :

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

> Description: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Release: 16.04

Codename: xenial

---

I tried a lot of things , installed a lot of packages, stopped some services but can't resolve.
I have 3 domains and will add some more too , so I want to use plesk for easy configurations, but can't install.
How can I install plesk on my system?

Comment: I assume you tried https://gridscale.io/en/community/tutorials/plesk-autoinstaller-ubuntu/ then?

Comment: Yes i started from there even :)

Comment: Then please add that kind of information to your post. Without knowing [what you've already tried](/help/how-to-ask) you might be making people waste a lot of time finding you solutions that you already tried =)

Comment: Installed what I see, a lot of packages, but didn't work. Than rebased system to initial snapshot , that was clean installation without any configuration but again same error. I think it's all about Plesk, it may doesn't work on ubuntu 16.04 LTS I think. Because I saw a note here (https://docs.plesk.com/release-notes/onyx/software-requirements/), about Ubuntu 16.04 ( Plesk only supports Debian 8 and Ubuntu 16.04 servers running the ‘systemd’ init system. Compatibility with ‘sysvinit’ has not been tested and is not guaranteed.) but i couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Please don't put additional information in comments, edit your post to add those details so that they the question stays self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you encountered system repositories misconfiguration.
Plesk requires that the system repositories were enabled.

For experiment sake I installed OS from official `ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso` with default settings (just enter-enter-enter):

```
# cat /etc/*release | grep VERSION
VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
```

Then Plesk Onyx 17.8 (which is currently default) using one-click installer.

Installation went successfully.
I can see, that mentioned packages depends on `libsnmp30`, but not the specific version:

```
# apt-cache depends plesk-php56-snmp
plesk-php56-snmp
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libsnmp30
  Depends: plesk-php56
```

However, the version which you were missing was already installed:

```
# dpkg -l | grep libsnmp30
ii  libsnmp30:amd64                    5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4.1                      amd64        SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) library
```

It comes from `xenial-updates main` repository, which is enabled by default:

```
# apt-cache showpkg libsnmp30 | grep  4.1 | grep binary-amd64
5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4.1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
```

Just in case, here is my `sources.list`:

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -v "^#"
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you explain , what does "Plesk only supports Debian 8 and Ubuntu 16.04 servers running the ‘systemd’ init system. Compatibility with ‘sysvinit’ has not been tested and is not guaranteed." mean ?

Comment: `systemd` initialization system is used as default in most major Linux distributions (RHEL staring from version 7, Ubuntu from version 15.04).
Earlier, `SysV` and it's improved version, `Upstart` were used. While it is still possible to boot Ubuntu 16.04 using `Upstart`, such scenario was not properly tested, thus, correct work cannot be guaranteed.
You can check which init system is used by running `ps -p 1`. `SysV` and `Upstart` will return `init`, `systemd` - `systemd`.

Comment: Additionally, I would like to mention, that init system is operating on a low level and it is mostly dealing with service management. I can assure you that it is not related to aforementioned package issue.

Comment: i had this problem and was missing
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
once added this seemed to fix things

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure why this happens but its definitely sure you need to install libsnmp30 dependency try this one

```
sudo apt-get install snmpd libsnmp30 libsnmp-base
```

or this one If that still gives you  errors and prevents installation (though, it doesn't look like it should that appears to be a different problem) try this:

```
sudo apt-get install snmpd libsnmp30 libsnmp-base linux-image-generic linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic
```

Comment: First one , installed snmpd libsnmp30 libsnmp-base packages, but plesk gave same error.

When tried second one :

`E: Unable to locate package linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic'
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic'
`

Comment: @mevaka can y execute a simple sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade or y get the same error? i think you have some problems with your updates some corruption am i right?

Comment: I did it hundred times , but no way, unfortunately each time getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem at the end, it's all about my version : it was 16.04.***3*** , not 16.04

So , i had to reinstall operating system, changed operating system to **16.04 LTS** (not *16.04.3* ) , and now I able to install Plesk.

It means , Plesk Supports only 16.04 solely , don't waste your time if you use another version of 16.04 , look for another control panel or change your operating system, there is no other way i think.

I wish it helps someone who will waste time cause of this simple information..

---

EDIT :

@Elvis Plesky answered the question, I think so Plesk supports minor versions. Maybe my configurations were incorrect , I don't know, because  already reinstalled OS.

Maybe it is about '**systemd**' thing that I found on Plesk documentation :

> Plesk only supports Debian 8 and Ubuntu 16.04 servers running the
>   ‘systemd’ init system. Compatibility with ‘sysvinit’ has not been
>   tested and is not guaranteed.

I am not an experienced user so don't understand what is it about..

Comment: That is actually not correct. Plesk supports minor LTS version upgrades, like Ubuntu 16.04.3 or Debian 8.4. Check out my answer.